# Не получаю значение ключа(int) из среза

Tags: golang

Есть 2 аналогичных примера

```
countryCapitalMap = make(map[string]string)
countryCapitalMap["France"] = "Paris"
countryCapitalMap["Italy"] = "Rome"
countryCapitalMap["Japan"] = "Tokyo"
countryCapitalMap["India"] = "New Delhi"

for country := range countryCapitalMap {
   fmt.Println("Capital of",country,"is",countryCapitalMap[country])
}
```

Результат:

```
Capital of France is Paris
Capital of Italy is Rome
Capital of Japan is Tokyo
Capital of India is New Delhi
```

Т.е. я получаю как значение ключа, так и значение по ключу.

Вариант 2

```
x2 := make(map[int]string)
x2[5] = "message"
x2[1] = "Hello"
for key := range x2 {
    fmt.Println("key[" + string(key) + "] is: " + x2[key])
    if x2[key] == "message" {
        delete(x2, key)
    }
}
```

Результат:

```
key[] is: message
key[] is: Hello
```

Почему в данном случае я не получаю значение ключа?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    x2 := make(map[int64]string)
    x2[5] = "message"
    x2[1] = "Hello"
    for key := range x2 {
        fmt.Println("key[" + strconv.FormatInt(key, 10) + "] is: " + x2[key])
        if x2[key] == "message" {
            delete(x2, key)
        }
    }
}
```

Для приведения типов есть отдельный пакет, используйте его, так же int64 (что то вроде расширенного типа) нужно юзать повсеместно. Всего доброго!

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Посмотрел документацию по пакету https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#example_FormatInt , возник вопрос, а что за base? FormatInt(i int64, base int)

Comment: @SergeiR Это система счисления. Двоичная, восьмеричная, десятичная, и т.д.